# Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined on my Jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following Jquery function inside my view:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#album-list").mouseover(function () {
                $(this).animate({ height: '+=15', width: '+=15' })
.animate({ height: '-=15', width: '-=15' });
            });
        });
  </script>
```

i have added the following scripts to the _layout view:-

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but when i navigate to the view that contains the above Jquery function; the following error will be raised  ""Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$'"". So what might be the problem?
BR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you loading your scripts after your inline script? The inline script must be placed after jquery is loaded.

If that is the case, please check the location of your jquery scripts.

Comment: the scripts are placed in the shared _layout view which will be rendered before all the other views, so i am sure that the scripts are being loaded before the inline script. BR

Comment: Not necessarily, you could be loading the external scripts at the end of the _layout view. Open your _layout view and check if they show up before the RenderBody call.

Comment: ok done. u are right the scripts were loaded after the renderbody call.

Answer (score 0):

Run [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) and see if you're getting any 404's and make sure that your files are all actually loading.  If they are, move your jQuery script include tags above the rest of your JavaScript.